# I want to create a custom searchbar in objective-c in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a custom searchbar looking like the following [custom search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAq4r.jpg)
but i haven't managed to duplicate this. This search is from another app we have in android phones and tablets.

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: you can look into this https://www.appcoda.com/custom-search-bar-tutorial/

Comment: For achieving that you have to make or design image using Designing team

Comment: Do you want complete code for implementing?

Comment: if possible. I made something close to the one i want

Answer (score 0):

Use UITextfield and set background image same like you have custom image and than use  NSPredicate for searching.

```
 NSPredicate *predk = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", searchString];
    NSArray *filtered = [your-Data-Array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predk];
```